# Пример необходимости Interlocked

Tags: c#

Подскажите, пожалуйста, пример когда необходимо использовать класс Interlocked (желательно код). То есть не простые фразы из книг о необходимости и преимуществах использования этого класса, а конкретный примеры когда без Interlocked не работает, а с ним все хорошо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        List<int> list = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToList();
        int cnt = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            cnt = 0;
            Parallel.ForEach(list, (element) =>
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < 1000; k++)
                {
                    cnt += element;
                }
            });

            Console.Write(cnt);                
            Console.Write(" - ");

            cnt = 0;
            Parallel.ForEach(list, (element) =>
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < 1000; k++)
                {
                    Interlocked.Add(ref cnt, element);
                }
            });

            Console.WriteLine(cnt);                
        }
```

Вот такой код все таки в некоторых случаях показывает что без класса Interlocked сумма получается неправильная

Answer (score 3):

Нужен этот класс тогда, когда есть несколько потоков и есть доступ к разделяемой переменной, которую они могут модифицировать.

Например ты запускаешь `Parallel.ForEach` и желаешь видеть кол-во выполненных итераций, что бы видеть некоторый прогресс. Поэтому за пределами цикла ты объявил переменную `cnt`.

Так вот, если в делегате ты будешь ее просто инкрементировать через `++` и выводить на консоль, то ты увидишь, что может быть бред из-за конкурентного доступа.

Для того, что бы это увидеть я сделал вот такой мини пример:

```
    int cnt = 0;
    var list = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000).ToList();
    var options = new ParallelOptions() {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8};
    Parallel.ForEach(list, options, (element) =>
    {

        var localCnt = Interlocked.Increment(ref cnt);
        if(localCnt!= cnt)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}",cnt, localCnt, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    });
```

Как видно, мы в небольшом случае попадем в условие `if`, когда несколько потоков параллельно модифицировали переменную и та переменная, которую мы локально себе сохранили не равна тому, что в данный момент содержится в `cnt`.

Результат выводимый в консоль будет не стабильным, так как напрямую зависит от того, как ОС спланирует эти потоки. А может так случится, что звезды сойдутся и проблем не будет.

А если бы мы это делали через простой ++, то в LocalCnt мы рисковали получить то, чего не ожидали.

Comment: добавь еще пример кода

Comment: Добавил пример.

Comment: @iluxa1810 У меня почему то и во втором случае выдает значения вразноброс

Comment: @Tzarek наверное я действительно наврал про четкий порядок вывода, ведь доступ к консоли мы не синхронизируем. Тем не менее, в первом примере значения могут повторятся из-за конкурентного доступа, а во втором это исключено. Не сложно догадаться, что некорректное значение в первом примере может поломать какие-нибудь вычисления.

Comment: @iluxa1810 К сожалению, не получилось увидеть какой либо особенной разницы между этими двумя примерами( В обоих случаях все в разнобой, но и не повторяются значения

Comment: @Tzarek, на скольких элементах в коллекции ты пробовал?

Answer (score 0):

Чтение или запись логических значений отдельно , но "сравнение и обмен" выполняет как чтение, так и запись на один и тот же адрес, что означает, что целая транзакция не атомарная. Если несколько потоков могут записываться в это же место, вам нужно сделать всю транзакцию атомарной, используя класс Interlocked.

Пример:

```
Int32 val = 5;
Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref val, 90, 5);
Console.WriteLine(val);
```

Результат:
`90`